# Reinitialize global/static memory at runtime or static analysis of global/static variables

Tags: c, memory, static, initialization, global

## The Problem

I'm working on a large C project (C99) that makes heavy use of global variables (I know, I know). The program works fairly well, but it was originally designed to run once and exit.

As such, it relies on it's global/static memory to be initialized with 0 (or whatever value it was declared with), and during runtime it modifies these variables (as most programs do).

However, instead of exiting on completion, I want to run the program again. I want to make a parent program that has control and visibility into this large program. Having complete visibility into the running program is very important.

The solution needs to work on macOS, Linux, and Windows.

I've considered:

### 1. Forking it

Make a small wrapper program that serves as the "shell", and execute the large program as needed.

#### Pros

- OS does the hard work of resetting the memory to the correct values
- Guaranteed to operate as intended

#### Cons

- Lost visibility into the program
- Can't inspect memory of executing program from wrapper during runtime, harder to tweak settings before launching, harder to collect runtime information
- Need to implement a system to get internal data in/out of the program, potentially touching a lot of code
- Unified experience harder (sharing a GUI window, etc)

### 2. Identify critical structures manually

Peruse the source, run the program multiple times, wait for program to blow up on a sanity check or bad memory access.

#### Pros

- Easy to do
- Easy to start
- High visibility, code sharing, and unification

#### Cons

- Does not catch every case, very patchwork
- Time consuming

### 3. Refactor

Collect all globals into a single structure to `memset`, create initializers for variables that are initialized with a value. Handle statics on a case-by-case basis.

#### Pros

- Conceptually easy, sledgehammer approach
- High visibility, code sharing, and unification

#### Cons

- Very time consuming, codebase large, would touch pretty much everything

### 4. Magic wand

Tell the OS to reinitialize global/static memory. If I need to save a value, I'll store it locally and then rewrite it when it's done.

#### Pros

- Mostly perfect :)

#### Cons

- Doesn't exist (?)
- Very black magic
- Probably not cross platform
- May anger 3rd-party libs

## What I am doing now

I am going with option 2 right now, just making my way through the code, leaning on the program to crash and point me in the right direction.

I'd say this method has gotten me about 80% of the way there. I've identified and reinitialized enough things that the program, more or less, can be rerun. It's not as widespread as I thought, and it gives me a lot of hope.

Occasionally, strange things happen or it doesn't operate as intended, but it also doesn't crash. This makes tracking it down more difficult.

I just need something to get me that last 20%. Maybe some sort of static analysis tool, or something to help me go through the source and see where globals are touched.

Comment: Static variables in functions can be really problematic — you might even argue that they should be made file scope.  Use method 2 extended to _"for each file that defines any global variables, add a `void filename_reset(void)` function that resets all the global variables to defaults"._  If that isn't zero, you'll need a constant version of the non-default data that can be copied over the modified version.  Don't skip any global variables — until you know you can do so safely.  Then arrange to generate a sequence of calls to `filename1_reinit(); filename2_reinit();` etc. — one call per file.

Comment: Option number 1 is the only real option. Option number 2 requires that you have the source code for every piece of code that goes into your executable. That includes 3rd party libraries, which you may have. But it also includes the C run time, and C standard libraries, which I'm pretty sure you don't have.

Comment: @user3386109: The standard C libraries don't cache much unless you count locale setting (and the restarted code probably needs to consider whether locales have been set — but will probably be able to say "no").  Libraries outside the C library are another matter — there could easily be problems there.  Functions that aren't thread-safe in the POSIX library could present problems — `getpwent()`, for example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `errno` for example. The information maintained by `malloc`. Information about open files. Even the strings that `argv` points to, which the program is allowed to change. All cleaned up when the program exits, but won't be cleaned up if you just tell the program to start over.

Comment: @user3386109: … and memory allocated but not freed; environment variables set (not part of standard C, though).  There are enough possibilities that restarting software not designed to be restarted (by using too many global variables and not cleaning up resources generally) is very problematic.

Comment: Just to clarify, the program manages it's dynamic memory very well, it frees everything it allocates, manages file handles cleanly, etc. Any 3rd party libs will be added by me for the wrapper program; the existing program is standalone, single threaded. It's really a well behaved program, and I have no doubt that it can be designed to be restartable, the question is the simplest way to do that without introducing so many bugs.

Answer (score 1):

To detect easily the global and static variables you can try [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com) and execute a cqlinq query like this one

```
from f in Fields where f.IsGlobal || f.IsStatic
select f
```

You can also modify the query if you want the variables used by a speific function or in a specific file.